# React "is not a function" problem in my todo list program

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and doing a todo list tutorial. I decided to add an "updateTask" function myself.
When you click the edit button, it turns the task text into an input field and it grabs the value of that input field along with the ID and runs "updateTask" function in App.js

It's basically the same code as "handleToggler" in App.Js (right under updateTask) which updates the state of the checkbox being checked or not.

However, I am getting an error that says "const tasksLeft = tadoState.filter(tado => !tado.completed) is not a function. This is right above the return statement in app.js and it is unrelated to the change I made so I've kind of been stuck.

I console.logged tadoState and a bunch of other stuff I changed to try and see where i messed up but it seems like the state is indeed changing just like I want it to. So I don't know what is causing the error.

```
APP.js 

import Tasklist from './Tasklist.js';
import './index.css';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';



function App() {
  // State of Task List
  const [tadoState, setTadostate] = useState([]);
  
  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = 'tadoApp.tados'

  //  GET Local Storage and setState
  useEffect(() => {
    const tadoStateLS = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY))
    if (tadoStateLS) setTadostate(tadoStateLS)
  },[])
  
  // SAVE to Local Storage when there is a change to tadoState
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(tadoState))
  }, [tadoState])
  

  // Reference to Input Value
  const addTodoRef = useRef();
  
  // Add new Task
  const addNewTadoHandler = (ref) => {
    // Grab value from input field
    const tadoValue = ref.current.value;
    // Check for user input
    if (tadoValue === '') return 
    // setState
    setTadostate(prevTadoState => {
      return [...prevTadoState, { id: uuidv4(), name: tadoValue, completed: false }]
    })
    ref.current.value = null;
  }

  // Update Existing Task
  const updateTask = (id, value) => {
    const newTadoState = [...tadoState]
    const updatedTask = newTadoState.find(tado => tado.id === id)
    updatedTask.name = value
    setTadostate(updatedTask)
  }

  // Enter to Add
  const enterToAddHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      addNewTadoHandler(addTodoRef);
    }
  }

  // Checkbox Toggler Function
  const handleToggler = (id) => {
    // Make sure to clone state and then modify. Spread original state. Find item, toggle, and then setStates
    const newTadoState = [...tadoState];
    const tadoToggle = newTadoState.find(tado => tado.id === id)
    tadoToggle.completed = !tadoToggle.completed;
    setTadostate(newTadoState);
  }

  // Clear Completed Tasks
  const clearTasksHandler = () => {
    const newTadoState = tadoState.filter(tado => tado.completed === false);
    setTadostate(newTadoState);
  }

  const clearAllTasksHandler = () => {
    setTadostate([]);
  }

  const clearTaskHandler = (id) => {
    const newTadoState = tadoState.filter(tado => tado.id !== id);
    setTadostate(newTadoState);
  }

  // # of tasks left
  const tasksLeft = tadoState.filter(tado => !tado.completed); 
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container-sm" style={{textAlign:'center', marginTop:"100px"}}>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
            <h1 className="fw-bolder">TADOSKY</h1>
            <p className="fw-light">All Tasks</p>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="row align-items-center">

                {/* INPUT FIELD */} 
                <div className="col-10">
                  <input onKeyDown={enterToAddHandler} ref={addTodoRef} type="text" className="form-control" style={{width:"107%"}} />
                </div>

                {/* ADD BUTTON */} 
                <div className="col-2">
                  <button onClick={() => addNewTadoHandler(addTodoRef)} className="btn bg-black text-white fw-bold m-2">+</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {/* CLEAR COMPLETED BUTTON */} 
            <button onClick={clearTasksHandler} className="btn btn-outline-dark fw-lighter m-2 px-3">Clear Completed Tasks</button>
            
            {/* CLEAR ALL */} 
            <button onClick={clearAllTasksHandler} className="btn btn-purple text-white m-2">Clear All</button>

            {/* # of Tasks left */} 
            <p className="mt-3 ">{tasksLeft.length} Tasks tado!</p>  

            {/* TASKLIST */}  
            <Tasklist tadoState={tadoState} updateTask={updateTask} handleToggler={handleToggler} clearTaskHandler={clearTaskHandler} /> 
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
      
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
TadoInput.js 
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function TadoInput({tado, editableState, updateTask}) {
    const editRef = useRef()

    const newInputHandler = (e) => {
        const value = editRef.current.value
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            updateTask(tado.id, value)
        }       
    }

    if (editableState === false) {
        return (
            <div className="card-title">
               {tado.name}
            </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="card-title">
                <input onKeyDown={newInputHandler} ref={editRef} type="text" style={{width: "300px"}} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in the code you can spot that I'm missing?

Comment: `updateTask` passes a single todo to `setTadoState`, instead of an *array* of todos. THe rest of your code seems to assume that `tadoState` is an array (a todo object doesn't have a `.filter` method, hence the error).

Comment: @FelixKling thank you changing the value in setTadoState worked.